# Ubuntu encrypt SSD + /home (HDD)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption

I have an SSD and HDD.

When installing Ubuntu I want "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and also "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security".

This makes my /home under SSD but I would like to have it under HDD but also encrypted. How can I make this?

**EDIT**:

```
sda                       8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                    8:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                    8:3    0 222,4G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt          253:0    0 222,4G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 206,4G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0  15,9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 931,5G  0 part  
  └─home_drive          253:3    0 931,5G  0 crypt /mnt
```

- swap resize it will be a next step (or even disable)

Comment: See this for an idea of how to create custom encrypted partitions during advanced installation. Once you have done the `/boot`,  `/` and `swap` partitions in SSD, you can do a fourth one `/home` in the HDD. Link: http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/28/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-encrypted-mbr-partitions/

Answer (score 3):

Ah, custom partitioning. This is a fun one, especially when you're trying to encrypt cross-volume. I'm going to assume you don't want to go [overly crazy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=40688917#40688917) (yes, that is my partition structure) and use LVM inside of LUKS here. I'm also going to assume you've already installed things, as it makes this process a tiny bit easier.

### Part I: Setting up your LUKS Partition

You're going to have to start by creating a new EXT4 partition on your hard drive. Make it take up as much space as you want.

Next, you will need to run `cryptsetup` to actually set up encryption. The command you want will be:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdXY
```

Replace `/dev/sdXY` with whatever is pointing at your new EXT4 partition. You will be prompted to choose a password. Choose a strong one and *write it down*. You will not have to remember it by the time you're done (you'll see why as we get further into this post).

Next, we need to make another `ext4` partition inside of your LUKS container, which will eventually go on to hold `/home`. These commands will achieve this:

```
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdXY home_drive
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/home_drive
cryptsetup close home_drive
```

Next, run `blkid` and make a note of the UUID of your new LUKS container (at `/dev/sdXY`). You'll need it in a sec.

### Part II: Enable Automatic Decryption

Now, we need to set up something called `decrypt_derived`, which allows you to "chain" decryption operations.

By doing this, we will allow one password to work across both drives. In effect, your decrypted first drive will be the password for your second drive. Your password (chosen above) will still work in case of an emergency (think data recovery or similar).

Run the below commands/file edits. Be sure to rename `ubuntu_crypt` to whatever your current crypt is called (see `/etc/crypttab` to find this). Also replace `/dev/sdXY` with your new LUKS partition.

```
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived ubuntu_crypt > /tmp/home_keyfile
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdXY /tmp/home_keyfile
shred -u /tmp/home_keyfile
```

Next, you will want to add the following line to `/etc/crypttab`:

```
home_drive UUID=<your_drive_uuid> ubuntu_crypt luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived
```

If you're using an SSD for your home drive, be sure to replace `luks,keyscript=...` with `luks,discard,keyscript=...`.

### Part III: Add to `/etc/fstab`

Now that your system is set up and can auto-mount the drive, we need to make `/etc/fstab` aware of this.

Fortunately, this is just a single line that needs to be added below the `/` entry in `/etc/fstab`. This line will look something like:

```
/dev/mapper/home_drive    /mnt    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
```

### Part IV: Testing it out

Next, you're going to want to mount your new (ready to go!) home partition. Your commands will be something like:

```
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdXY home_drive
mount /dev/mapper/home_drive /mnt
```

Copy your current home folder over to the new drive, and make sure everything looks good.

Finally, you just need to run the below command to make your system aware of your crypt:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Reboot your system, and make sure you'll only have to enter your password once. If you need to do it more than once, something went wrong. Double-check all of your steps.

Once you're back online, confirm that `/mnt` has all of your home data present in it.

### Part V: Moving for real

Now, you're going to want to re-open `/etc/fstab` again, and edit your new line, replacing `/mnt` with `/home`. It should look like this:

```
/dev/mapper/home_drive    /home    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
```

Save the file.

Run `update-initramfs -u -k all` one more time, and reboot your system.

Once you're back up, run `lsblk` and make sure your homedir is mounted to the new drive.

Once you're happy, you'll need to get rid of your old home data. The problem is that a mount will replace the current folder with itself, so there's no way to access that data (and you can't delete your homedir while running). So, you'll need to do a bindmount:

```
mount --bind / /mnt
```

Run `touch /mnt/home/test`, and then immediately run `cat /home/test` and make sure it complains that the file is not found. If the file is found, something is wrong with your mount config.

Once you're sure that `/home/test` does not exist but `/mnt/home/test` does, you can go ahead and delete your old home with `rm -rf /mnt/home/*`.

Your system will now be on your SSD and your homedir will be on its own encrypted drive!

Comment: I can't get it to work in Part IV.
If i make a `ls -a /mnt` only appears lost+found. But if I try mount again says it's already mount on `/mnt`.

When I reboot it goes for maintenance mode. The way I have to get de pc running again e comment the added line on `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @gohan Please edit your original question with the results of the `lsblk` command.

Comment: Also, on first mount, you'd *expect* that to only contain `lost+found`. You just need to copy your userdir (so `/home/gohan`) there. After that, `ls /mnt` should contain a `gohan` folder.

Comment: Seems that `keyfile=/lib/....` doesn't work. I managed to get it working with `keyscript=/lib/...`

Comment: @Gohan oh, wow. you're right! Sorry about that typo!

Comment: At Part IV, reboot is asking for the password.
When I do `cryptdisks_start home_drive` it doesn't ask for password.
`etc/crypttab` seems good. I edited the question with `lsblk` after the mount in Part IV.

Am I missing something?
For copying home it's just `cp -r /home/gohan /mnt` ?